# Why is WiringiPi unable to find hardware revision?

Tags: gpio, pi-3b+, ubuntu, wiringpi

I installed [Ubuntu 18.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/beta/) on a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ and WiringPi following the instructions presented [here](http://wiringpi.com/download-and-install/). The problem is that when calling the GPIO utility, I get the following error:

[image]

It seems that the hardware line is missing from /proc/cpuinfo:

```
processor       : 0
model name      : ARMv7 Processor rev 4 (v7l)
BogoMIPS        : 38.40
Features        : half thumb fastmult vfp edsp neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm crc32 
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xd03
CPU revision    : 4
```

Is there something I can do to make it work? Can I modify the cpuinfo file, or there is no solution other than using another linux image?

Comment: Please don't use images for text output, instead paste the text direct into the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WiringPi is not supported on any other operating systems than Raspbian - so its likely this feature is not supported in Ubuntu.

> WiringPi is developed directly on a Raspberry Pi running 32-bit Raspbian. I do not support any other platform, cross compiling or operating systems. It has been ported to other platforms, other operating systems and some are cross compiling, however this author does not maintain those systems. If you are trying to use wiringPi on a platform other than the Raspberry Pi with Raspbian then you must contact the person who did the port and not me.

http://wiringpi.com

**EDIT: WiringPi is now deprecated** http://wiringpi.com/wiringpi-deprecated/

Comment: OK. Do you know a tutorial/some instructions on porting/compiling wiringPi to/for Ubuntu?

Comment: No, sorry. Why not use Raspbian?

Comment: I want to use the latest version of Tensorflow which does not give any warnings when run. I obtained this using Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: Why not run Tensorflow on Raspbian?

Comment: @CoderMike OP does not want to see warning msgs. On Raspbian you get 1 or 2 warnings (that are absolutely harmless and can be ignored).

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get wiringPi to work in my IoT edge module. What I ended up doing is using "onoff" as my GPIO node module instead of wiringPi.

const BME280 = require("bme280-sensor");
Gpio = require("onoff").Gpio;
const LED_RED = new Gpio(LEDPin, "out");

Hope it helps.